# "Keyword argument not understood" - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

System information

```
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Raspberry Pi 3B+ (latest dist)
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): pip
TensorFlow version (or github SHA if from source): 1.11.0 (latest from pip)
Keras version: 2.2.4 (latest from pip)
```

Hello,
I am trying to accelerate a CNN model in order to run it in python and on my raspberry pi. I've tried using tensorflow lite as a solution to this but I still have no success in converting my keras model to a lite one and use it afterwards. I've tried tflite_convert on the command line but I get the error quoted below. I've also tried using the TocoConverter inside python and also using the TFLiteConverter and tflite_convert on a machine with fully updated tensorflow and keras but I still get the same error. Could you help me?

Provide the text output from tflite_convert

raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:' , kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:' , u'output_padding')